# Whats is the android equivalent for iOS web browser back-to-app button?

Tags: android, browser

In the android app that I'm developing, there is a requirement to open some web sites in external web browser.

When it comes to iOS apps, when you open an web page from external browser, the browser shows a "back to " button on top of the browser (on task bar) as depicted in the picture below (green box top left hand corner

[image].

User can click on that button and navigate back to the application where you open this browser

Is it possible to have such a button displayed in android app as well?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but keep in mind that Android devices have a hardware back button that provides the same functionality, so it's not really necessary.  They added this feature in this way on iOS due to the lack of a hardware back button, in essence giving iOS users functionality that Android has had for a long time.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But if you navigate deep in to the website that you've got opened in the external web browser, pressing the hardware back button take you to the respective previous page that you were on. It doesn't take you out of the web browser and back to the application. BTW it seems that this feature is not available in android.

Comment: It will get you out of the web browser and back to the application eventually, just keep clicking!  You're correct of course, it is a slightly different implementation.  Just to note, there are certain design patterns that both iOS and Android share, and there are other areas where the correct design for Android and iOS will be different.  Take a look at the respective apps of any of the major players to get an idea of what should be the same and what should be different.

Comment: Fair enough. Yes it's true that keep pressing the  back button take user back to the application eventually. It seems most of the popular apps behave in the same manner. Thanks.

Comment: If you are opening a web browser; I suggest you look into Chrome Custom Tabs. It basically opens chrome but inside your application just like starting a new activity. I guess then you won't face the problem which you mentioned in comments. here is the link https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: Thanks deepu513. This is what I was looking for. This works perfectly if the Chrome is installed in the system and user selects it to open the web pages. Even if the Chorme is not installed, it still works in the default manner.I think it'll be better if you can post this as an answer.